# Aztec encoder for Android

Tags: android

I am looking for Aztec encoding library which can convert a string to Aztec barcode image for use in my application.

I have seen ZXing http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ but it only does decoding (convert Aztec image into its textual representation). I am looking for encoder which can convert a string to Aztec image.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Yasir

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.2 ZXing does support Aztec encoding.

Answer (score 0):

RACO offer a [web based API](http://www.racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/2d/aztec-code.aspx) for generating Aztec and other barcodes.  It's not a library, but can easily be called from your app.

Comment: Thanks Terence, This is possible but for our requirement a web service may not be a viable option. Need 15 points to vote up which I dont have yet :(